# Bash POSIX Mode on window 10

Tags: bash, git, cygwin, window

I tried to use split command on window git bash shell. script is as below

```
test.sh
split -a 1 -p 'temp' file1.sql data-  && mv data-a data1.sql && mv data2.sql
```

it is failed with error:

```
split: unknown option -- p
Try 'split --help' for more information.
```

I read about -p for **Bash POSIX Mode** and see like it should work on **Cygwin** on window. I installed it and tried with it. It failed also with same error. It support on linux and mac. Is anybody idea what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

GNU `split` does not support `-p`. If you need to split on a pattern then use `csplit` instead.

Comment: ohk I see. Thanks so csplit support mv pattern?